# How can I find the positive solution of this system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the positive solution  for the system

$$x^{x+y}=y^n ;$$

$$y^{x+y}=y^n x^{2n}\quad     ;   n>0$$

I want help to find it's solutions.

Comment: $x=y=1$ is a solution. What class has assigned this as homework?

Comment: hint: multiply them together.

Answer (score 2):

Go with just a observation : (x,y)=(1,1) satisfy!

Second:
Multiply both eq. to get: $$(xy)^{x+y}=(xy)^{2n}$$

and done. $xy=1$ or $x+y=2n$ .

We substitute this in parent equations and get $y=x^2$ . so the solution is intersection of $y=x^2$ and $x+y=2$.

Comment: there are another set of solutions in: $x + y = -n$

Comment: But we don't want those solutions..... they give -ve solutions

Comment: You do not want negative solution in y, but i guess 'x' can be negative as it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @lsp I don't see what you mean. It's mentioned we want +ve solutions for system and "system" constitute (x,y)

Comment: Even i thought the same before, but i am not sure. In that case only $x+y=2n$ is the solution.

Comment: @exploringnet Given fixed $n$, there are only 2 solutions.

Comment: Okay.@IvanLoh I understant what u say.but not particularly 2 (even if n is fixed; other than 1) we can get x,y for x+y=2n ; when both not particularly n;

Comment: You still have to substitute $x+y=2n$ back into the equations, and you find that $y=x^2$. Similarly for $xy=1$.

Comment: Yep! agree @IvanLoh  thanx!

Answer (score 1):

$x^{2n}$ = $y^{x+y-n}$

$y$ = $x^{(x+y)/n}$. Substituting this in the $1st$ equation will give:

$x^{2n}$ = $x^{(x+y-n)(x+y)/n}$

When $x$ not equal to $1$ : $2n = (x+y-n)(x+y)/n $

Now let $x+y = p$ and you get a quadratic equation in $p$.By solving it you get the values for $p$ as : $-n$ and $2n$.

So, $p = 2n$ $\implies$ $x+y = 2n$ $\implies$ $y = 2n - x$

or $p = -n$ $\implies$ $x+y = -n$ $\implies$ $y = -n - x$